# "class not found" shows up even though I did it before In another viewController but it doesn't work

Tags: swift, import, classnotfound

I get this message and a lot of the time I am following a tutorial and it is the exact same code yet it says it is wrong then I turn off my computer and it fixes itself, is this normal?   my issue right now is that it "class not found"

I also move my file to use MVC but then it doesn't let me import UIKit and I have to remove it from the folder and then it works[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cst4v.jpg)

Comment: May you show your code, your link tutorial?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cst4v.jpg

Comment: You should paste here or codepen, we can be easy to test if need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change:

> var color2: UIColor -> color2: UIColor?

Because your variable color2 is not optional, you need init it before. So set it optional or set a default value for it.

Comment: thank you that solved the issue. that happens a lot sadly where it is a tiny error. I spent 5 hours today trying to find that. im new. thank you.